# Pattern matching issue in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the column "endpoint".
Some of the records in this column are equal to `/samples/delete/<something>` and some are equal to `/items/delete/<something>`.
The following query works fine and returns the expected records:

```sql
select endpoint from endpoints
where endpoint ilike '/samples/delete%'
```

The issue is that when I execute the following query, I get no results at all:

```sql
select endpoint from endpoints
where endpoint ilike '/(samples|items)/delete%'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the `~*` operator, not `ilike`. Add `^` to the start of the regex and remove `%` from the end, `'^/(samples|items)/delete'`.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to [Stefanov.sm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2302032/stefanov-sm)!
I replaced `ilike` with the `~*` operator, and modified the pattern to `^/(samples|items)/delete`.